# RNN - What are timesteps?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I am completely new to the recurrent neural network models. I am using rnnlib to run their examples. What is the meaning of timesteps in the output ? Do timesteps mean that number of output the RNN outputs ?

For example-:

Output-: A,B,C

Will the timesteps here be 3 since it has generated 3 outputs ?

Here is a sample output from rnnlib-:

```
training...
data sequence:
file = arabic_offline.nc
index = 0
tag = data/pf416_008.tif
input shape = (365 129 1)
timesteps = 47085
target label sequence (length 8):
maE laB aaE seB laA zaE naM maB
output label sequence (length 4):
naB raA haE raA
weight_optimiser weight updates:
minmax(wts) = -0.100045 0.100051
minmax(derivs) = -7.27329 5.25175
minmax(deltas) = -0.000525175 0.000727329
output shape = (21 121)
errors:
ctcError 82.4798
deletions 4
insertions 0
labelError 8
seqError 1
substitutions 4

data sequence:
file = arabic_offline.nc
index = 1
tag = data/dj21_024.tif
input shape = (642 103 1)
timesteps = 66126
target label sequence (length 13):
teE laM maM jaM laB aaA kaA waE seB seE naB waE taB
output label sequence (length 2):
naB raA
weight_optimiser weight updates:
minmax(wts) = -0.10034 0.100256
minmax(derivs) = -12.2291 5.46554
minmax(deltas) = -0.00101921 0.00187751
output shape = (36 121)
errors:
ctcError 140.356
deletions 11
insertions 0
labelError 12
seqError 1
substitutions 1
```

What is the meaning of timesteps here ?